# Django Attribute Error module object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I've been wrecking my brain for the past day trying to work out what I've done wrong. I changed some code in my app and got multiple error message. I changed it back however and the errors still appear. The only files I had changed were settings.py and admin.py which are not even referenced in the traceback.

I do realise its not much to go on but I'm totally stuck so if anyone could send me in the right direction it would be a great help!

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
web_1  |     utility.execute()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
web_1  |     django.setup()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
web_1  |     app_config.import_models(all_models)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
web_1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
web_1  |     __import__(name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/models.py", line 265, in <module>
web_1  |     class _Str(models.Func):
web_1  | AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Func'
web_1  | Unknown command: 'createinitialrevisions'
web_1  | Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.
web_1  | ==> /srv/logs/access.log <==
web_1  | 
web_1  | ==> /srv/logs/gunicorn.log <==
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
web_1  |     utility.execute()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
web_1  |     django.setup()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
web_1  |     app_config.import_models(all_models)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
web_1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
web_1  |     __import__(name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/models.py", line 265, in <module>
web_1  |     class _Str(models.Func):
web_1  | AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Func'
booking_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Looks as though you may have an incompatible version of reversion

Comment: In particular, there seems to be no class `Func` among your models.